# blackberry setup email problem

Tags: blackberry

i have blackberry bold 9700 device with 6.0 os. 
In setup screen -> email accounts -> when i tap this then 2 option display:

- internet mail account
- enterprise account.

when i tap first  option then one prompt display. 
That is your device had a problem connecting to the server.
i have wifi connection. I dont understand. please suggest me. And also suggest me BIS

account  is compulsory for open email account. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is about questions related to programming

Answer (score 0):

You need BIS or BES from your service provider in order to activate push-email. Once activated, you can receive e-mail via Wi-Fi but you'll still need the BIS/BES subscription.

Alternatives are [Shangmail](http://bb.anworm.com/free-blackberry-push-mail-with-shangmail/)  and [LogicMail](http://www.logicmail.org/)

Comment: Thanks for giving answer but it is not useful for me. realy thanks.